# Button to change dropdown selection and reload widget with new selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, mindbody

I have to incorporate a Healcode widget (through Mind Body) into the site I'm working on. My goal is to have a button on that page change the dropdown selection of the Healcode widget and reload the widget to reflect the dropdown change.

So far I've been able to create a button that changes the dropdown selection to the desired value when clicked. However it does not reload the widget to reflect the change. I still have to manually click the dropdown to make that happen.

Any help is appreciated!! Here's what I have so far:

**HTML FOR THE HEALCODE DROPDOWN FILTERS:**

```
<div class="filters">
        <select name="mbo_class" id="mbo_class">
<option value="">All Classes</option><option value="58">200 hour Teacher Training</option>
<option value="3">Basics</option>
<option value="59">Basics/Power</option>
<option value="85">Basics/Restore + Meditation</option>
<option value="156">Cozy Winter YIN &amp; Restore</option>
<option value="23">Deep Stretch/YIN</option>
<option value="154">Express Power</option>
<option value="140">HIIT Power Yoga</option>
<option value="12">Music &amp; Power Yoga</option>
<option value="5">Power Yoga </option>
<option value="46">Power Yoga/Restore </option>
<option value="138">Simply Stretch</option>
<option value="30">Tween Yoga</option>
<option value="139">YOD (Yoga + HIIT)</option></select>
</div>
```

**HTML & JS FOR BUTTON TO CHANGE THE SELECTION:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn3").click(function(){
    $("#mbo_class").val("3");
  });
});
</script>
<button id="btn3">Set Value</button>
```

I'm thinking a working solution might be somehow capturing what the dropdown is changed to and then reloading the page, but my attempts have not worked thus far. Here's my latest attempt:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn3").click(function(){
    $("#mbo_class").val("3");
  });

  var selectedProduct = sessionStorage.getItem("product");
if(selectedProduct != undefined || selectedProduct != null){
    $("mbo_class").first().find(":selected").removeAttr("selected");
  $("mbo_class").find("option").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == selectedProduct) {
                $(this).attr("selected", true);
            }
        });
}

$('mbo_class').change(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem("product", $("mbo_class").first().val());

  location.reload();
});
</script>
<button id="btn3">Set Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution! It isn't quite the direction I was planning to go, but it works! Since I can't actually change the HTML of the widget–the research I was doing led me to a lot of dead ends.

---

In the HealCode widget app, I created a version of the schedule widget for each class type (the filter options mentioned above).

Then I set the button to change the *entire div id* to display the correlated schedule widget. (Rather than just filtering the current schedule widget.)

We'll use the example of filtering for the "Basics Class".

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="widget-container">
  <healcode-widget data-type="schedules" data-widget-partner="object" data-widget-id="3c106917a43" data-widget-version="0">
</healcode-widget>

<a id="schedule-basics" class="button">Basics schedule</a>
```

Here's the script–which changes the schedule displayed to the "Basics Class" schedule (much like the filter selection would):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var scheduleWidgetMarkup = '<healcode-widget data-type="schedules" data-widget-partner="object" data-widget-id="3c1218147a43" data-widget-version="1" ></healcode-widget>';
    $('body').on('click', '#schedule-basics', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#widget-container').html(scheduleWidgetMarkup);
    });
  });
```